# Debian Preseed: Malformed IP address

Tags: debian, preseed, debian-bullseye

I am trying to deploy a Debian 11.6 host using preseed.

This is my config:

```
# This preseed file was rendered from the Foreman provisioning template "Preseed default".
# for s293.example.org running Debian 11 
# Organization: Default Organization
# Location: FRA1

# Locale
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US
# country and keyboard settings are automatic. Keep them ...
# ... for wheezy and newer:
d-i keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap seen true

# Static network configuration.
d-i preseed/early_command string /bin/killall.sh; /bin/netcfg
d-i netcfg/disable_autoconfig boolean true
d-i netcfg/dhcp_failed note
d-i netcfg/dhcp_options select Configure network manually
d-i netcfg/disable_dhcp boolean true
d-i netcfg/get_ipaddress string 12.123.12.149
d-i netcfg/get_netmask string 255.255.255.224
d-i netcfg/get_nameservers string 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220
d-i netcfg/get_gateway string 12.123.12.129
d-i netcfg/confirm_static boolean true

# Network configuration
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select auto
d-i netcfg/get_hostname string s293.example.org
d-i netcfg/get_domain string example.org
d-i netcfg/wireless_wep string

d-i hw-detect/load_firmware boolean true


# Mirror settings
d-i mirror/country string manual
d-i mirror/http/hostname string ftp.debian.org:80
d-i mirror/http/directory string /debian
d-i mirror/http/proxy string
d-i mirror/codename string bullseye
d-i mirror/suite string bullseye
d-i mirror/udeb/suite string bullseye

# Time settings
d-i clock-setup/utc boolean true
d-i time/zone string UTC

# NTP
d-i clock-setup/ntp boolean true
d-i clock-setup/ntp-server string 0.debian.pool.ntp.org

# Set alignment for automatic partitioning
# Choices: cylinder, minimal, optimal
#d-i partman/alignment select cylinder



# Use the first detected hard disk
d-i partman/early_command string \
  INSTALL_DISK="$(list-devices disk | head -n1)"; \
  debconf-set partman-auto/disk "$INSTALL_DISK"; \
  debconf-set grub-installer/bootdev "$INSTALL_DISK"

### Partitioning
# The presently available methods are: "regular", "lvm" and "crypto"
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm

# If one of the disks that are going to be automatically partitioned
# contains an old LVM configuration, the user will normally receive a
# warning. This can be preseeded away...
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
# The same applies to pre-existing software RAID array:
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
# And the same goes for the confirmation to write the lvm partitions.
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true

# For LVM partitioning, you can select how much of the volume group to use
# for logical volumes.
d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max
d-i partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name string vg00



# You can choose one of the three predefined partitioning recipes:
# - atomic: all files in one partition
# - home:   separate /home partition
# - multi:  separate /home, /var, and /tmp partitions (/usr was removed in jessie)
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select atomic


# If you just want to change the default filesystem to something
# else, you can do that without providing a full recipe.

# This makes partman automatically partition without confirmation, provided
# that you told it what to do using one of the methods above.
d-i partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true




# User settings
d-i passwd/root-password-crypted password $5$2CwBetOMHDO2Vc9b$J2qdiojE2bhaFqWjbTuH7D3sxdY6mguSFIqZ6hcR9AB
user-setup-udeb passwd/root-login boolean true
d-i passwd/make-user boolean false
user-setup-udeb passwd/make-user boolean false





# Install minimal task set (see tasksel --task-packages minimal)
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect minimal, ssh-server, openssh-server

# Install some base packages
d-i pkgsel/include string lsb-release wget
d-i pkgsel/update-policy select unattended-upgrades
d-i pkgsel/upgrade select none

popularity-contest popularity-contest/participate boolean false

# Boot loader settings
#grub-pc grub-pc/hidden_timeout boolean false
#grub-pc grub-pc/timeout string 10
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true
d-i finish-install/reboot_in_progress note

d-i preseed/late_command string wget -Y off http://foreman.example.org/unattended/finish -O /target/tmp/finish.sh && in-target chmod +x /tmp/finish.sh && in-target /tmp/finish.sh
```

Now I am getting this message:

[image: debian installer]

The network is 12.123.12.128/27, gateway being 12.123.12.129 .

The logs are not really helpful to me:

[image: debian installer error log]

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: is the ip 12.123 a public ip or a private one? due 208.67.222.222 I assume that the ip will be near the range

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Nevermind, I found your other post on the foreman community forums, and the answer: https://community.theforeman.org/t/debian-preseed-malformed-ip-address/31668 and I also archived it on the wayback machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20230922183801/https://community.theforeman.org/t/debian-preseed-malformed-ip-address/31668